# Jquery multiple onchange events - dropdown lists and input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

What i would like to have is sort of this which doesnt work:

http://jsfiddle.net/adige72/BS9rp/

If i select an option, all values of input text fields change but in fact i would like to only one text field to be populated which is next to that dropdown list i select from.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways to do this including using `id`'s on the fields but using your fiddle, you could do this:

```
$(this).next($('.phonenumber')).val($(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-phonenumber'));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible with jquery. On the example in that link you are selecting based on the class of the input boxes "phonenumber". If you select based on the the actual control Id it will not populate all the input boxes on the screen. Please see below for example:

```
$("#dropdownlistID").live("change", function() {
    $("#inputfieldID").val("update with whatever you want");
})
```

Comment: Due to my lack of reputation i couldn't vote your answer up but thanks anyway (:

Comment: No problem, just glad I could help Adige72

Answer (score 0):

Yea. Use unique ids for each drop down and text field and that will get you in the right direction.

```
    <select id="IDX" class="name" name="name[]">
    ...
    <input id="textIDX" type="text" class="phonenumber"...
    ...
    $('#IDX').change(function(){
       $('#textIDX').val('anything....');
    });
```

Comment: Didn't try that but if you say so, i'll keep in mind that. Thanks.